# How to ease Nginx when a big file is included in the configuration?

Tags: nginx

so I had a problem with DDoS, I think I solved it, but the solution is causing me problems.

After months of suffering and trying almost everything I finally solved the problem by blocking IPs one by one and denying them with the command:

`deny ip;`

I included all the denied IPs in a file, which I am including to my configuration. Now the file contains more then 1.9 million IPs, I cannot block IP ranges, just specific IPs.

Nginx is now taking too long to restart. If I split the included file into two files of 900 000 or four files of 500 000 will this make a difference?

Is there any way I can make Nginx check the file / files faster?

Comment: Just set up fail2ban and block only the IPs that are currently causing problems. I doubt that you need to block so many IPs all of the time.

Comment: Sadly, I do need to ban all of them, the attack is constantly changing IPs. I tried fail2ban several times, but did not do the job.. The load was still over the top.

Comment: Then you put them in an ipset and ban them from the host firewall.

Answer (score 2):

With a file of that size I would not do it in nginx, but in iptables instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
# here's your list of IPS
CURRENT_BL=/path/to/my/ip_black_list.txt
# create/flush recreate the tables
iptables -F BLACKHOLE
iptables -N BLACKHOLE 
for BAD_IP in $(cat $CURRENT_BL)
do
        ipset add ipset-blacklist $BAD_IP 2>/dev/null || \
                echo "Failed to add ${BAD_IP}"
done
# REJECT the matching target
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -p all -m set --match-set ipset-blacklist src -j REJECT 
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -j RETURN
# assume your nginx is on 80 and 443
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j BLACKHOLE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

This allows you to append new IPs with:

```
ipset add ipset-blacklist X.X.X.X
```

Without reloading your nginx or the entire list. It's quite performant

**Edit:**

To get all the above working you'll need to install ipset and iptables

```
apt-get install iptables ipset
```

To make these rules permanent, you would use iptables-save and iptables-restore to save the currently-defined iptables rules to a file and (re)load them (e.g., upon reboot).

So, for instance, you would run

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.conf
```

to save your current iptables rules to /etc/iptables.conf and then insert these lines in /etc/rc.local:

```
# Load iptables rules from this file
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

don't forget to make sure /etc/rc.local is executable

Edit 2: this version splits the list into two ipsets, one for ipv4 and the other for **ipv6**, not checked the syntax of anything except the regex but should work.

**Warning** the regular expression is really really long, make sure you copy the entire line

```
#!/bin/bash
# here's your list of IPS
CURRENT_BL=/path/to/my/ip_black_list.txt
# create/flush recreate the tables
iptables -F BLACKHOLE
iptables -N BLACKHOLE 
# inverse regex matches everything except ipv6 addresses
for IPV4 in $(egrep -v "(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))" $CURRENT_BL)
do
        ipset add ipset-blacklist-ipv4 $IPV4 family inet 2>/dev/null > /dev/null
done
# regular expression matches only ipv6 addresses
for IPV6 in $(egrep "(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))" $CURRENT_BL)
do
        ipset add ipset-blacklist-ipv6 $IPV6 family inet6 2>/dev/null > /dev/null
done
# REJECT the matching target
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -p all -m set --match-set ipset-blacklist-ipv4 src -j REJECT 
ip6tables -A BLACKHOLE -p all -m set --match-set ipset-blacklist-ipv6 src -j REJECT 
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -j RETURN
# assume your nginx is on 80 and 443
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j BLACKHOLE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hmm, I was not aware of this approach. Where should I add the above configuration? And I am including all the blocked IPs automatically with awk command from the console. Can I do the same with this approach?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab Absolutely, two alternatives 1) have the AWK command populate the /path/to/my/ip_black_list.txt with a single IP address per list or 2) have the AWK command return a single IP per line to std out and replace the `for` loop line above with: `awk [..your..program..] | while read BAD_IP`. That done you'd run this script (it'll apply immediately) - and either call it on boot, or save and restore the resulting rules using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`

Comment: @Nazikambe One more question, I have to install iptables with the following command  `sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent` and than edit this file `sudo nano /etc/iptables/rules.v4` an apply the configuration that you gave me above? Thank you in advance!

Comment: And if I block the ips with iptabes, what will the blocked users see in the browser when they try to enter the website? Maybe a 403 error message?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab if you block an IP with iptables, its firewalled at a network level. Someone trying to access any service on your server will either get a connection that never completes (you used `-j DROP`) or a connection refused message (you used `-j REJECT`)

Comment: To get this working on ubuntu you'd need to `apt-get install iptables ipset`

Comment: @Nazikambe Thank you for the clarification, and just one last thing, where should I make the configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89980/discussion-between-emmanuel-ab-and-nanzikambe).

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you make the configuration persistent

Comment: Thank you, I will test this and give an answer right away!

Comment: I tried running this, however, then I have ips as this one `2c0f:f8f0:fa0c:0:e417:9806:dee9:8397` it is failing. Any idea why is that?

Comment: As I was bought out to me in order to block both IPv4 and IPv6 I need to have two different ipsets. As for the IPv6 set I must use `ip6tables` Is there any way I can implement this in the above script, or should I do a separate script for the IPv6?

Comment: answer amended with an ipv6 supporting version

Comment: Hey there, I implemented everything and if I try to enter the website by the server IP I am blocked (I blocked my ip to test it), however, the website has CloudFlare and when I try to get from the domain I am getting in, so are the bots. Any suggestions?